# Performance review (unofficially) delayed

Tags: performance-reviews, developer, europe, covid-19

I am a junior Software Developer working his first job out of college at a medium-sized (a few hundred employees worldwide) IT company. When I was hired, I was told by HR that the first performance review would take place after my first six months with the company.

Problem is, almost two weeks have passed since I reached that milestone and nobody (neither my manager nor my HR) has approached me about it yet, and I don't know what should I do.

In our company we're encouraged to ask HR 'about anything that we don't know who to ask'. However, as we all know, "HR is not friend", and I'm afraid this might have repercussions on the person who was supposed to perform my review and/or I might be frowned upon for going straight to HR about this.

I understand that the COVID-19 pandemic happening right now is a tough time for everyone, and I suspect that it may have something to do with the delay. However, my current pay is about average (if not slightly lower) when compared to the market rate for my job in my city, and I could really use the extra money.

How could I handle this situation in a professional manner?

If it matters, this is in Eastern Europe.

Comment: Have you asked your direct manager about the performance review?

Comment: Just casually ask your manager. Some.

Comment: @sf02 No, I haven't talked to anyone (including my direct manager) yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our performance reviews are held yearly, at the end of the calendar year.  They're supposed to be done by Dec 1, but that very seldom happens.  Some may be done by mid November, while others aren't completed until the end of January.

So as you can see there usually a great deal of variability in when a reviews actually takes place, vs when its supposed to take place.  I would not worry about a several week lag, particularly given what's happening in the world.

If you just want a warm fuzzy, ask your manager/supervisor directly, or ask via email or whatever works for you in your company.

Answer (score 2):

Don't assume ill will where confusion and forgetfulness explain the situation. I imagine the person whose task is to do your review has been thinking about other things in the present health crisis.

You should avoid making a big deal about this. Just remind them, politely and casually, that your review is due. You can do this by asking, "is there anything I should do to prepare for my review?"

I worked for a company once where the policy was to delay reviews for underperforming employees.  That was a REALLY bad policy, because another reason for review delays was underperforming managers (lazy, never finishing things like reviews on time). This company was infested with underperforming managers. So late reviews were crazy-making especially for good employees.

But that is NOT your problem. Your problem is that everybody is up to their ears in alligators (viruses). So be cool about it. And be healthy.